# Issue with ST_CONTAINS and ST_WITHIN in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

My environment: PostgreSQL 11.4 with PostGIS 2.5.2

```sql
CREATE TABLE m_polygon (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, bounds POLYGON);
INSERT INTO m_polygon(bounds) VALUES( 
  '(0.0, 0.0),  (0.0, 10.0), (10.0, 0.0), (10.0, 10.0), (0,0)' 
);

SELECT ST_WITHIN(m_polygon.bounds , m_polygon.bounds ) FROM m_polygon;
```

I am getting the error message for SELECT statement above:

```
ERROR:  function st_within(polygon, polygon) does not exist 
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might 
need to add explicit type casts
```

I was thinking what the reason for the error is:  the ST_WITHIN arguments types should be GEOMETRY, but I am passing the POLYGONs.

However  the following works:

```sql
SELECT ST_WITHIN(ST_MakePoint(1,1), ST_MakePoint(1,1) ) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`POLYGON` is Postgres native type. `Geometry` is the type used in PostGIS. `ST_...` functions are Postgis functions.

Note that you can restrict a PostGIS geometry to a specific subtype (`geometry(POLYGON)`)

If you don't want PostGIS, you would need to use [native geometry operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html).

If you are to use spatial data, and since you already have PostGIS, it is much better to switch to true geometries:

```sql
CREATE TABLE m_polygon (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, bounds geometry(POLYGON));
INSERT INTO m_polygon(bounds) VALUES( 
  st_geomFromText('POLYGON((0.0 0.0, 0.0 10.0, 10.0 10.0, 10.0 0.0, 0.0 0.0))') 
);

SELECT ST_WITHIN(m_polygon.bounds , m_polygon.bounds ) FROM m_polygon;
```

Comment: Do you think I can solve the issue using the casting as here: 
 
    SELECT ST_WITHIN(
              CAST(bounds as GEOMETRY) , 
              CAST(bounds as GEOMETRY) 
     ) FROM m_polygon;

Comment: Choose your battle. It may work but you won't be able to use spatial index and will have to do cast every single time you want to use a Postgis function... Just use the proper data type in the 1st place!